# push notification is not working in iOS in react-native-fcm

Tags: react-native

I have added firebase for the push notification in my react native application but i am only getting in android not in iOS. I have checked all the set up in my xcode and firebase all are correct but still i am not able to get notification message in iOS. Any one can help me to resolve this issue.
.

Comment: Have you submitted your APNs authentication key to firebase?

Comment: yes. i have submitted APN Auth key  and also enabled the push notifications in app id despite am not able to get push notification using react-native-fcm ?.

Comment: Are you testing in a simulator on or the device?